# Python algorithm to return all two-tuple permutations of numbers up to n

Tags: python

I have a Python function like so:

```
def get_values(n: int) -> list:
    """
    :param n: the maximum absolute value
    :return: sorted list of all the positive and negative permutations up to size n
    """
    if n < 0:
        return []

    if n == 0:
        return [(0, 0)]

    out = set()
    for i in range(0, n + 1):
        for j in range(0, i + 1):
            out.add((i, j))
            out.add((-i, j))
            out.add((i, -j))
            out.add((-i, -j))
    return sorted(out, key=lambda t: abs(t[0]))
```

The `sorted` at the end is important for my use case.

The issue is this uses a large amount of memory, presumably because it appends 4 values for every j. So as n becomes large, this set becomes very large.

I used a set rather than a list since I gathered it should take less memory by avoiding duplicates (I may be wrong :))

I would like to reduce the memory of this so can be large, up to 10,000 would be ideal but the bigger the better. Speed isn't really an issue here but faster is better!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd say your code is well-structured and easy to read. The approach however can be simplified using the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module from the standard library. `itertools` provides useful implementations for things like `combinations`, `permutations`, cartesian `product` and a lot more.

Here's the simplest and fastest approach I could come up with, that is equivalent to your implementation:

```
from itertools import product

def valid_tuple(number_pair: tuple) -> bool:
    a, b = number_pair
    return abs(b) <= abs(a)


def get_values_product(n: int) -> list:
    out = product(range(-n, n + 1), repeat=2)
    out = filter(valid_tuple, out)
    return sorted(out, key=lambda t: abs(t[0]))
```

It's usually faster to use functions that are built-in or included in standard library modules. [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) returns the cartesian product of input iterables, which is exactly what we want here. On my machine, this takes about half the time of your original implementation.

---

<s>As you need sorted output I don't think there's a way to significantly reduce the space complexity. If you didn't need the output to be sorted, you could turn it into a [generator](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/), which is really memory-efficient.</s>

**Edit:**

Here's how you can get the same desired sorted output while optimising space complexity:

```
from itertools import product, chain
from typing import Generator

def get_values_generator(n: int) -> Generator:
    if n < 0:
        return

    numbers = chain(*zip(range(n + 1), range(-1, -n - 1, -1)), [n])

    pairs = product(numbers, repeat=2)

    yield from filter(valid_tuple, pairs)
```

This works because we already *pre-sort* the list of numbers before calculating the cartesian product. This implementation returns a `generator object`, i.e. an iterator instead of a list. This means you might have to make some slight adjustments to the code that uses the return value of `get_values`.

Here's a comparison of the memory used by the return values of both approaches:

```
num = 50

sorted_list = get_values(num)
generator_obj = get_values_generator(num)

print(sys.getsizeof(sorted_list))
print(sys.getsizeof(generator_obj))
```

prints

```
> 85176
> 112
```

When changing `num = 500`, we get:

```
> 8448728
> 112
```

As you can see, the memory used by the `generator object` is constant at 112 bytes.

Here's some validation regarding the correctness of our result:

```
print("Same elements:\t", set(sorted_list) == set(generated_list))
print("Same length:\t", len(sorted_list) == len(generated_list))
print("No duplicates:\t", len(generated_list) == len(set(generated_list)))

print("Sorted:\t\t\t", all(abs(x[0]) <= abs(y[0]) for x, y in zip(generated_list, generated_list[1:])))
```

We get the same output for negative and positive numbers, as well as zero:

```
> Same elements:     True
> Same length:       True
> No duplicates:     True
> Sorted:            True
```

Comment: I guess it doesn't have to be sorted, the reason it is sorted is it finds an equation for a multivariable function using a saddle point, local maxima and local minima and returns Ax^2+Bx+Cx^2+Dy+k. This function is used for values A,B,C and D so clearly you want to return the smallest values hence why it will go 0,1,-1,2,-2.... Check here (https://pastebin.com/gr2KbvQb) if you want to see the full code. This isn't really the place to talk about this so if you think it's better I can open a new question and link it here.

Comment: I see. I think there should be an approach that produces already sorted output, which could then be returned element-by-element without the need to sort first. That should significantly reduce space-complexity. I will have a look at that later tonight!

Comment: @GAP2002 I provided an additional approach, that will reduce the memory usage of the return value to a constant 112 bytes. Intermediate objects inside the function are even smaller (`numbers` takes up 48 bytes of memory, while `product(numbers, repeat=2)` takes up 80 bytes).

Comment: @riskypenguin nice review, you can use `yield from product(numbers, repeat=2)` to save one line of code.

Comment: In the original code, `j` only went up to `i`.  In this code it goes up to `n`. That is, the second element in the tuple is always <= the first element.  Don't know if that's important or not.

Comment: @Marc Thanks, I implemented your suggestion!

Comment: @RootTwo You're absolutely right, thanks for spotting that! I fixed it for both my approaches, by checking for valid tuples. `get_values_product` still takes about half the time of OP's approach, and `get_values_generator` is the fastest in my testing, even when consuming the entire iterator.

Answer (score 5):

This is how you can do this without appending four times

```
def get_values(n: int) -> list:
 """
 :param n: the maximum absolute value
 :return: sorted list of all the positive and negative permutations up to size n
 """
 if n < 0:
    return []

 if n == 0:
    return [(0, 0)]

 out=list(range(-n,n+1)) '''list of all positve 
 and negative numbers'''

 out=list({(i,j) for i in out for j in out})
 return sorted(out, key=lambda t: abs(t[0]))
```

In your original code some cases were missing

Comment: Your first assignment of `out` can be simplified to `out = range(-n, n+1)`, there's no need for two seperate set comprehensions.

Comment: It seems like we both ran into the same mistake, as was pointed out by RootTwo in the comments to my answer: *In the original code, `j` only went up to `i`. In this code it goes up to n. That is, the second element in the tuple is always <= the first element.* Another small note: There's not need to create a `list` from `range` object if you only need to iterate over it. `out = range(-n, n+1)` will suffice.